# Is it faster to use with_limit_and_skip=True when counting query results in pymongo

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I'm doing a query where all I want to know if there is at least one row in the collection that matches the query, so I pass `limit=1` to `find()`. All I care about is whether the count() of the returned cursor is > 0. Would it be faster to use `count(with_limit_and_skip=True)` or just `count()`? Intuitively it seems to me like I should pass `with_limit_and_skip=True`, because if there are a whole bunch of matching records then the count could stop at my limit of 1.

Maybe this merits an explanation of how limits and skips work under the covers in mongodb/pymongo.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your intuition is correct. That's the whole point of the `with_limit_and_skip` flag.

With `with_limit_and_skip=False`, `count()` has to count all the matching documents, even if you use `limit=1`, which is pretty much guaranteed to be slower.

From the [docs](http://api.mongodb.org/python/1.4/api/pymongo/cursor.html#pymongo.cursor.Cursor.count):

> Returns the number of documents in the results set for this query. Does not take limit() and skip() into account by default - set with_limit_and_skip to True if that is the desired behavior.